# How do I use all the command line arguments for a tool in a Bash wrapper script?

Tags: bash, arguments

I have a written a wrapper script for a tool and I only exposed few command line arguments of the tool but i am wondering how do i get all the command line arguments of the tools inside the wrapper script?

Here is the tool that I am interested in:

```
hisat2 [options]* -x <hisat2-idx> {-1 <m1> -2 <m2> | -U <r> | --sra-acc <SRA accession number>} [-S <hit>]

Options    
Input options
-q
Reads (specified with <m1>, <m2>, <s>) are FASTQ files. FASTQ files usually have extension .fq or .fastq. FASTQ is the default format. See also: --solexa-quals and --int-quals.    
--qseq
Reads (specified with <m1>, <m2>, <s>) are QSEQ files. QSEQ files usually end in _qseq.txt. See also: --solexa-quals and --int-quals.   
-f
Reads (specified with <m1>, <m2>, <s>) are FASTA files. FASTA files usually have extension .fa, .fasta, .mfa, .fna or similar. FASTA files do not have a way of specifying quality values, so when -f is set, the result is as if --ignore-quals is also set.    
-r
Reads (specified with <m1>, <m2>, <s>) are files with one input sequence per line, without any other information (no read names, no qualities). When -r is set, the result is as if --ignore-quals is also set.    
-c
The read sequences are given on command line. I.e. <m1>, <m2> and <singles> are comma-separated lists of reads rather than lists of read files. There is no way to specify read names or qualities, so -c also implies --ignore-quals.
```

In my wrapper script I was able to expose all mandatory options of hisat2 tool.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
      echo ""
      echo "Usage : sh $0 -i Input_folder -l lib_type {-1 <left_reads> -2 <right_reads> | -U <single_reads> | -s <sra_id>} -S <output_sam> -p numb_threads"
      echo ""

cat <<'EOF'
  -i </path/to/input folder>

  -l Library type

  -1 </path/to/reads_1>

  -2 </path/to/reads_2>

  -U </path/to/single_reads>

  -S </path/to/sam output>

  -s SRA ID

  -p Number of threads

EOF
    exit 0
}

while getopts ":hi:l:1:2:U:S:s:p:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    i)
    input_folder=$OPTARG # Input folder
     ;;
    l)
     lib_type=$OPTARG # Library type
     ;;
    1)
    left_reads=$OPTARG # Left reads
     ;;
    2)
    right_reads=$OPTARG # Right reads
     ;;
    U)
    single_reads=$OPTARG # single end reads
     ;;
    S)
    sam_out=$OPTARG # Samoutput file
     ;;
    s)
    sra_id=$OPTARG # SRA ID
     ;;
    p)
    num_threads=$OPTARG # Number of threads
     ;;
    h)
    usage
     exit 1
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done


for i in $input_folder/*; do
    cp $i .
   fbname=$(basename "$i" .ht2 | cut -d. -f1)
done

if [ ! -z $left_reads ] && [ ! -z $right_reads ];
then
    hisat2 -x $fbname --rna-strandness $lib_type -1 $left_reads -2 $right_reads -S temp.sam -p $num_threads
    samtools view -bS temp.sam > $sam_out
    rm temp.sam
fi
```

When i looked at the optional arguments there are more than 20 of them and yes i can manually expose them all in my wrapper script but i am wondering if there is a way to do it programmatically.

Comment: Why do you have the wrapper?  I think it is a not a great idea for the wrapper to worry about all the command line arguments of the thing that you are wrapping.

Comment: I need the wrapper because the original tool does not work the way that i wanted.

Comment: Does the wrapper itself have any arguments of its own?

Comment: Yes couple of them only

Comment: Got it, please see the answer I just posted.  Hope this would make sense to you.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into it. I am not a programmer but a biologist and so will take time to understand it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the command you are writing the wrapper for has a complex set of arguments, I think it is best to do this:

- Write the wrapper so that it is called as:

  `wrapper args -- args_for_the_wrapped_command`
- Grab all arguments until `--` in the wrapper and pass the rest of them to the wrapped command, without having to worry about what those arguments actually mean
- Check for the exit code of the wrapped command appropriately so that we catch any errors caused by wrong arguments

This way, the wrapper doesn't need to deal with the complexity of parsing wrapped command's arguments.

Something like this:

```
#
# grab all arguments meant for the wrapper
#
declare -a args_for_wrapper
for arg in "$@"; do
  if [[ "$arg" == "--" ]]; then
    shift  # get rid off "--" itself
    break
  else
    # the argument consumption logic can be placed here as well
    # or collect the args into an array
    args_for_wrapper+=("$arg")
    shift
  fi
done

# consume wrapper's argument contained in the array

# call the wrapped command
wrapped_command "$@"
```

Makes sense?

However, this approach may not work if the wrapper is supposed to construct all the arguments for the wrapped command, optionally mixing it with what it receives through its own command line.